# In React Redux How I check Ordered Items Every product stock or not

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, redux, mern

I want to check my all ordered item stock using each order item product id.

---

**Process Order React Page**
[image: Process Order React Page]

---

**Order items Redux State**

[image: Order items Redux State]

---

**All Products State**
[image]

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots. And, what do you want to check?

Comment: I want to check every ordered items current stock

Comment: Heres the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dhawan-w06lm?file=/src/App.js